# C# proxy windows form application

Tags: c#

This code has an error : `method must have a return type`. How can I solve it?

```
public Server()
{
}
```

the error is on the server word above

```
public void createListener()
{
    TcpListener tcpListener = null;
    IPAddress ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").AddressList[0];

    try
    {
        tcpListener = new TcpListener(ipAddress, 13);
        tcpListener.Start();
        output = "Waiting for a connection...";
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        output = "Error: " + e.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(output);
    }

    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10);
        TcpClient tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[256];
        NetworkStream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
        stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        SocketHelper helper = new SocketHelper();
        helper.processMsg(tcpClient, stream, bytes);
    }
}
```

Where should I add it ?

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.Run(new Server());
}
```

Comment: `public class Server
{
}`

Need to say what kind of object a `Server` is

At the moment, your code is assuming Server is a method and should have a return type on it. since you're calling `new Server()` in your Main and your getting the error requesting a return type, I'm assuming you meant to create a class object and you haven't declared the class at the top of you class file
`public Server()
{
}` Would work if you are using it as a constructor, but that should be:

`public class Server
{
public Server()
{
}
//Other methods
}`

Comment: If you copied the code from this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397809(v=vs.90).aspx), you must put the code in a separate class. Create a new class, name it Server then copy the code into it.

Comment: I created 3 classes

Comment: Where should I put the class sockethelper ?

Comment: Each class in a specific file. Name the file as your class name.

Answer (score 0):

Between the words "public" and "Server" you need the type of object you are going to return. If you do not want to return anything, then you would want to use "void" in place of the return type.

In your provided code, you have "new Server ()", so you are probably wanting to define server as a class type.